# Modifying strings inside a list in Python

Tags: python

**I want to create a program that transforms a list from this:**

```
['H.Geffner/AI:FromProgramstoSolvers7', 'R.DeSousa.', 'R.Dechter.', 'H.Dreyfus.', 'J.Elster.', 'J.Evans.Dual-processingaccountsofreasoning,judgment,', 'H.Geffner.Heuristics,planning,cognition.InR.Dechter,', 'H.Geffner,andJ.Y.Halpern,editors,', 'H.Geffner.Computationalmodelsofplanning.', 'M.Genesereth,N.Love,andB.Pell.Generalgameplay-', 'G.Gigerenzer.', 'G.GigerenzerandP.Todd.', 'A.Gopnik,C.Glymour,D.Sobel,L.Schulz,T.Kushnir,and']
```

**to this:**

```
['H.Geffner', 'R.DeSousa', 'R.Dechter', 'H.Dreyfus', 'J.Elster', 'J.Evans', 'H.Geffner', 'H.Geffner', 'H.Geffner', 'M.Genesereth', 'G.Gigerenzer', 'G.Gigerenzer', 'A.Gopnik', 'C.Glymour', 'D.Sobel', 'L.Schulz', 'T.Kushnir']
```

All the names are separated from the other information by '.', 'and' or ','

Iv'e tried separating them by counting the number of '.' it has and when it reaches 2 it appends that item to a new list without the extra info but I think there might be a different way of doing it.

This is what I've got so far.

```
names = (the huge list I showed above)
just_names = []
current_name = ""
number_of_periods = 0
for item in names:
    index = 0
    while index < 8:
        if item[index] != ".":
            current_name = current_name + item[index]
           # print(current_name)
            index = index + 1
        else:
            number_of_periods= number_of_periods+ 1
            index = index + 1
            if ponto >= 2:
                just_names.append(current_name)
                current_name = ""
```

Comment: I suggest using [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Comment: Should't `'G.GigerenzerandP.Todd.'` produce `G.Gigerenzer` and `P.Todd` since both names are separated by `and`? `P.Todd` does not exist in your desired output.

Comment: Why `N.Love` is not in the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do that is to use a regex:

```
import re

data = ['H.Geffner/AI:FromProgramstoSolvers7', 'R.DeSousa.', 'R.Dechter.', 'H.Dreyfus.', 'J.Elster.', 'J.Evans.Dual-processingaccountsofreasoning,judgment,', 'H.Geffner.Heuristics,planning,cognition.InR.Dechter,', 'H.Geffner,andJ.Y.Halpern,editors,', 'H.Geffner.Computationalmodelsofplanning.', 'M.Genesereth,N.Love,andB.Pell.Generalgameplay-', 'G.Gigerenzer.', 'G.GigerenzerandP.Todd.', 'A.Gopnik,C.Glymour,D.Sobel,L.Schulz,T.Kushnir,and']

regex = r"^(\w+\.?\w+)"
matches = [re.search(regex, item) for item in data]
names = [match.group(0) if match else None for match in matches]

print names
```

Since you're asking the question, I'm guessing you don't know about them. The syntax is a bit ugly but they are very useful in some cases.

Check out [This website](https://regex101.com/r/Wo9dmP/1) for an explanation of what `^(\w+\.?\w+)` means. This are the basics:

- `^` What we are looking for must be at the start of the string
- `(...)` we wrap the bit we want to extract in parentheses
- `\w` look for word characters (letters and numbers)

  - `+` quantifier for `\w`, match one or more of these
- `\.` look for a dot character

  - `?` quantifier for `\.` allow one or zero of those
- `\w+` same as before: one or more word characters, but after the dot

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

names=['H.Geffner/AI:FromProgramstoSolvers7', 'R.DeSousa.', 'R.Dechter.', 'H.Dreyfus.', 'J.Elster.', 'J.Evans.Dual-processingaccountsofreasoning,judgment,', 'H.Geffner.Heuristics,planning,cognition.InR.Dechter,', 'H.Geffner,andJ.Y.Halpern,editors,', 'H.Geffner.Computationalmodelsofplanning.', 'M.Genesereth,N.Love,andB.Pell.Generalgameplay-', 'G.Gigerenzer.', 'G.GigerenzerandP.Todd.', 'A.Gopnik,C.Glymour,D.Sobel,L.Schulz,T.Kushnir,and']
just_names=[]
for name in names:
    found=re.findall('[A-Z]\.[A-Za-z]+',name)
    for n in found:
        just_names.append(n)
print(just_names)
```

or 1 line answer:

```
import re

names=['H.Geffner/AI:FromProgramstoSolvers7', 'R.DeSousa.', 'R.Dechter.', 'H.Dreyfus.', 'J.Elster.', 'J.Evans.Dual-processingaccountsofreasoning,judgment,', 'H.Geffner.Heuristics,planning,cognition.InR.Dechter,', 'H.Geffner,andJ.Y.Halpern,editors,', 'H.Geffner.Computationalmodelsofplanning.', 'M.Genesereth,N.Love,andB.Pell.Generalgameplay-', 'G.Gigerenzer.', 'G.GigerenzerandP.Todd.', 'A.Gopnik,C.Glymour,D.Sobel,L.Schulz,T.Kushnir,and']
just_names=[n for l in [re.findall('[A-Z]\.[A-Za-z]+',name) for name in names] for n in l]
print(just_names)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['H.Geffner', 'R.DeSousa', 'R.Dechter', 'H.Dreyfus', 'J.Elster', 'J.Evans', 'H.Geffner', 'R.Dechter', 'H.Geffner', 'J.Y', 'H.Geffner', 'M.Genesereth', 'N.Love', 'B.Pell', 'G.Gigerenzer', 'G.GigerenzerandP', 'A.Gopnik', 'C.Glymour', 'D.Sobel', 'L.Schulz', 'T.Kushnir']
```

Answer (score 0):

the above regex wont cover the case of the 'and': I would suggest the following pattern:

```html
p = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]*[\.][a-zA-Z]+)\.*[and]*[\/]*")
```